# Wordpress same site content in different language for different domains

Tags: wordpress

We have a wordpress site which we are planning to serve in different language on different domains. I did a lot of research on Google and went through numerous articles regarding this topic. However, I can not decide where to start, so this forum is my last resort. Can anyone please guide me.

Here are facts which I hope will be useful to anyone willing to help:

- The site content will be same for all domains
- Different domain will serve different languages
- Users who comes to our main site, which is in English will be given a option to switch to their regional domain

What I need help with are as follows:

- How to do this? Would multisite be a good answer to this?
- If multisite is the solution, will it slow down our site? Given that we have same plugin and content for all domains
- Plugins for auto translations of the contents based on domain?

I really need to get this started, so any help is heartily welcome.

Comment: search for this plugin: polylang

Comment: Hi thanks for the plugin link.

Comment: Anyone else going to answer others questions, which are more confusing than the translation part.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the [Weglot Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/weglot/).
I am part of the co founding team, we are available to answer any questions and help.

Key features include:
- Easy integration: less than 3 minutes, then users only take care of translations
- Improved usability: a unique dashboard gathering all translations in a single place, offering the possibility to edit and purchase translations
- Complete and rich range of translations sources: a first layer of machine translation automatically offered at subscription; professional translations; users and their team members
- Optimized SEO: following Google best practice, Weglot creates unique URL (/en/page) for each language, all tags and meta translated,
- Fully compatible: Yoast, Woocommerce and many others
- Light plugin: keeping the full performance of the website
- 7/7 support: dedicated team only focusing on developing the best multilingual plugin experience